# How to reset port forwarding without a factory reset on a mikrotik router

Tags: port-forwarding

I was working on a network, that goes something like this: tp-link router -> mikrotik router -> splitter for computers. And it has wifi from both routers. I accidentally forwarded ports(the 80 port specifically) on mikrotik in such a way, that it redirects most ips(not all) to 192.168.1.1, which is tp-link settings, the mikrotik settings were on ip-address 192.168.2.1, which redirects to 192.168.1.1 too. So I cannot access the mikrotik settings. Same happens when connecting to it by wifi. Can I reset the port forwarding or fix this problem in some other way **without doing a factory reset**, as it will probably break a lot of things and dissrupt the workflow for a lot of people.

Sorry for being such a noob, because I used the wrong port.

Comment: For a device to be on-topic here, the manufacturer must offer optional, paid support. Unfortunately, MikroTik does not offer that. also, consumer-grade devices, e.g. TP-Link, are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].